# How to use Salesforce Dynamic Forms in Community Record pages?

Tags: lightning, community, lightning-record-page

Can we use the [Salesforce Dynamic Forms (Dynamic layouts)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_overview.htm&type=5) in Community Record pages? I know we could use it with Custom Object Record pages.

I couldn't find any known issue or limitations mentioning we can't use. It doesn't show Record page upgrade link as below in Community.

[image]

Comment: Upvote this idea : https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdbhOUAR/enable-dynamic-forms-dynamic-actions-for-the-communities-interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**. Dynamic Forms are available only in Lightning App Builder.

Here's the mention of this on the [Winter '21 release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab_dynamic_forms_ga.htm) (emphasis mine).

> It adds the ability to configure record detail fields and sections inside the **Lightning App Builder**.

Comment: Thanks @Jayant Das, Also found this idea for it: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V0000003hmAQAQ

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Forms for community can be achieved using this solution from Salesforce Labs. Its free.

[Extreme Dynamic Forms (EDF)](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3u00000QvqmaEAB&tab=e)

**Feature Highlights:**

1. Dynamic forms for Experience Cloud
2. Quick configuration setup from Page Layout
3. Add HTML Snippets to forms
4. Build client side validation
5. Conditional custom labelling
6. Build surveys/wizards using flows
7. Debug Mode for Admins.
8. Beautified browser Console Logs for Devs to debug and fix issue lightning fast
9. It supports all Salesforce objects including both standard objects & custom objects in the same form.
10. Setup conditional logic in the form of Boolean Expression (including lengthy and complex expression e.g. *(custom_field1__c = “some text” && standardField1 = 100) || custom_field1__c = “some other text”* - to show & hide fields and/or sections

[Setup and Installation Guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dM_wJMORMJHuPnUTXXGLT_z2uxZI7ylyQbg8ROZBhHI)